# Is there a name for the class of functions where the difference between the function and it's derivative is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Functions which satisfy

$|f(x) - f'(x)| < k$

for some finite $k$.

I've discovered that polynomials do not satisfy this, but exponentials and sines, and their linear combinations do. I was curious to find more functions which satisfy that condition, but can't think of any, and I don't know what terms I might search to find if others have looked at this.

Comment: I don't know of a term for it, but it's equivalent to $|(fe^{-x})^\prime|<ke^{-x}$.

Comment: I would be surprised if there was a name for this, because it's not a very interesting property.

Comment: Like @TonyK, I would be surprised if there was a name for this, but I would be a bit more positive: if you find a useful application for this property, then it is interesting and you get to choose a name for it.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. It was accidental, but now I can't take it back, since votes are locked after 12 hours.